# Kafka connect JDBC import failing to start

Tags: apache-kafka, ubuntu-16.04, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Attempting to load data to Kafka with the command `bin/connect-standalone etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/quickstart-sqlserver.propertiess` causes the error below to be shown. I've checked the content of **kafka-connect-s3-4.0.0.jar** and the referenced class isn't in the path mentioned.

```
[2018-04-01 22:53:55,887] INFO Loading plugin from: /opt/confluent-4.0.0/share/java/kafka-connect-s3 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:179)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/connect/storage/StorageSinkConnectorConfig
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:54)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:279)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:260)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:153)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:47)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.connect.storage.StorageSinkConnectorConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:62)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 22 more
```

The content of the file`quickstart-sqlserver.properties` is

```
name=test-sqlserver-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=sqlserver://**:1433;databaseName=****;user=**;password=**
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=event_nr
topic.prefix=test3-sqlserver-jdbc-
table.whitelist=support_notifications
schema.registry=dbo
```

The content of **connect-standalone.properties** is

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/opt/confluent-4.0.0/share/java
```

Please note that i get the same error regardless of whether i use the connect-standalone.properties file or if i use the schema-registry properties file.

Comment: What is the content of `etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties`?

Comment: Thanks Giorgos, I have added the content of **connect-standalone.properties**. I also have the error when i use **etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties** instead.

Comment: Have you installed Confluent on your local machine?

Comment: I unzipped the download of confluent 4.0.0 into the /opt folder

Comment: And under which directory are you trying to run the commands?

Comment: **/opt/confluent-4.0.0**